# File '.../node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-core/src' not found

Tags: typescript, hardhat

I setup a typescript hardhat project and it's working fine but in `/***/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../config/typescript/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../",
    "rootDirs": ["."],
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node", "chai"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../hardhat-core/src"
    },
    {
      "path": "../../hardhat-ethers/src"
    }
  ]
}
```

the references field is highlighted and it says `File '***/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-core/src' not found.`
and indeed it isn't there. How to fix that?

Comment: Did you install `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-core` ?

Answer (score 1):

use 'npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'